# mysql - select concat query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list all users beginning with a letter, e.g. D

Would the following be the right method of doing this.

```
Select concat(firstname, '',lastname) from users where concat(lastname) = "D*"
```

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT concat(firstname, '',lastname) FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE "D%"
```

If you want to use wildcards, you need the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator.  Also, in your where clause you only have one column (lastname), so you don't need [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Answer (score 0):

i would try:

```
select * from users where lastname like 'D%';
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting list starting with eg: "D":

```
SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE LEFT(firstname,1)= 'D';
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need `concat` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: in case of 'first name' value is null. script use the 'name' value from last name. Then it will list name start with 'D'

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What makes you think that any value is `NULL`?

Comment: I removed all of my assumptions @NicoHaase .  Now I write it as normal way.